# WCF + TDD : adding service references to your test projects: Bad?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, silverlight, tdd

I'm starting to TDD and I want to know if it is a bad practice to add a service reference to test my project or if I just mock a fake service on my tests that depends of the WCF service.

Comment: Is there any documentation detailing this?

Comment: I don't get it.   You want to TDD your service?  this is not TDD then and you should be creating TDD methods that create your actual service implementation (service class!)

Comment: and yes you should always be mocking a web service, never use a proxy reference.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a bad practice to add service references to a unit testing project. You could use the generated service contract interface to mock the real WCF service behavior in the test.

Comment: Also if you are into testing the WCF plumbing you could use your test framework thread as a host(MSTEST or other).  This assumes you are not using something like IIS as a host.

Answer (score 1):

Having a service ref is possible a bad way to go, you could consider implementing the Gateway Pattern, e.g. IMyFooServiceGateway as an additional abstraction layer. This way you might be able to make the app more loosely coupled and gain some additional testability (in you test project you'd reference the segregated assembly containing IMyFooServiceGateway and either hand-create a mock that implements IMyFooServiceGateway or use a mock framework like Rhino Mocks to create one for you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a service reference you could mock out a ChannelFactory using your service contract.

Comment: how is this anything near TDD?  TDD means you create tests first for a service that doesn't exist and implement the service as you write your failing tests.

Comment: I think the keyword in my sentence is mock. You will have the contract your service implements, you would then use a mocking framework (MOQ, etc) to give your tests something to run against. Something like mentioned here http://fczaja.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/mocking-wcf-client-with-moq.html.

Answer (score 0):

If the project which is the target for the tests has a service reference, you should not have to add an additional service reference to the test project.

When a service reference is added to a project, usually the code generated for it contains a publicly accessible interface to the service. The test project therefore only need reference the target project in order to see this interface, which can in turn be dropped into your mocking library of choice or mocked out manually.

It's worth noting though that the interface generated doesn't necessarily follow the typical "IFoo" naming convention for interfaces so it isn't immediately obvious.